# I can't increase variable's value when button clicked

Tags: javascript, json, promise, fetch

I just want to do this: (index++ or index-- when button clicked) but it's value doesnt change (always zero). I think I cant transfer some values. It must be increase or decrease?? There is two function. One is increase my index variable, other is decrease it. But eventually index stays as 0.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    const carousel_baslik = $(".carousel-baslik")[0];
    const carousel_metin = $(".carousel-metin")[0];
    const carousel_image = $(".carousel-image")[0];
    const counter = $("#counter")[0];
    const icon = $("#icon-ground")[0];
    const controller1 = $(".carousel-controller")[0];
    const controller2 = $(".carousel-controller")[1];
    var index = 0;

    class Request {
        get(url) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => resolve(data)).catch(err => reject(err));
            })
        }
    }
    const Requesting = new Request();
    Requesting.get("js/carousel.json").then(data => {
        const slides = data.length;

        controller1.addEventListener("click", function (slideCount) {
            geri(slides);
        });
        controller2.addEventListener("click", function (slideCount) {
            ileri(slides);
        });
        add(data);
    });

    function geri(slideCount) {
        index--;
        showSlides(slideCount);
        console.log("index:" + " " + index);
        console.log("slideCount:" + " " + slideCount);
    }

    function ileri(slideCount) {
        index++;
        showSlides(slideCount);
        console.log("index:" + " " + index);
        console.log("slideCount:" + " " + slideCount);
    }

    function showSlides(slideCount) {
        index = slideCount;
        if (index < 0) {
            index = slideCount - 1;
        }
        if (index >= slideCount) {
            index = 0;
        }
        // console.log(index);
    }

    function add(data) {
        carousel_baslik.textContent = data[index].baslik;
        carousel_metin.innerHTML = data[index].metin;
        carousel_image.src = data[index].image;
        counter.textContent = data[index].count;
        const img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = data[index].icon;
        img.className = "w-100";
        img.alt = "";
        icon.appendChild(img);
    }
});
```

result: always index 0

My last edit (Index increasing and decreasing but datas dont add to HTML):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    const carousel_baslik = $(".carousel-baslik")[0];
    const carousel_metin = $(".carousel-metin")[0];
    const carousel_image = $(".carousel-image")[0];
    const counter = $("#counter")[0];
    const icon = $("#icon-ground")[0];
    const controller1 = $(".carousel-controller")[0];
    const controller2 = $(".carousel-controller")[1];
    var index = 0;

    class Request {
        get(url) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(data => resolve(data)).catch(err => reject(err));
            })
        }
    }
    const Requesting = new Request();
    Requesting.get("js/carousel.json").then(data => {
        controller1.addEventListener("click", geri);
        controller2.addEventListener("click", ileri);
        add(data);
    });


    function add(data) {
        carousel_baslik.textContent = data[index].baslik;
        carousel_metin.innerHTML = data[index].metin;
        carousel_image.src = data[index].image;
        counter.textContent = data[index].count;
        const img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = data[index].icon;
        img.className = "w-100";
        icon.appendChild(img);
    }

    function geri() {
        index--;
        console.log(index);

    }

    function ileri() {
        index++;
        console.log(index);
    }

});
```

Comment: I think it's worth you having a read of the [mcve] page.

Comment: I realize that `showSlides` is probably a looping method, but have you tried commenting that out to see if that's the culprit? It immediately changes the index to the slide count, and then updates the index to either 0 or slideCount - 1.

Comment: You increase index and then next line you set it to another number when you call a function `index--;
        showSlides(slideCount);`

Answer (score 2):

You're increasing and decreasing `index`, but soon after this you're setting it back in `showSlides` function, when you set `index = slideCount`, so all your work is lost.